# The response of redux-saga call api

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to get a response as below and I could get using Postman.

**response**:

```
{
    title:"title."
    tags:['tag1', 'tag2']
}
```

But from redux-saga, I couldn't get a result as desired although I access to the same URL.

**response**:

```
{
    title:"title."
    tags:[]
}
```

Why the tags has no value from using redux-saga, whereas from Postman has some values.

Comment: I suspect the payload in your redux saga differs to the one you are using in postman. Also seeing the code of your saga and the payload in your postman might give some hints.

Comment: @MartinKadlec thank you for your replying. I could get the response data as desired in this morning,  but I didn't change my program.